# What's the probability of a pangram in a crossword occuring by chance?

Tags: probability

There are several sources of the percentage occurence of each letter in the English language.

So is it possible using these to calculate the probability of a crossword containing each letter of the alphabet at least once. (A pangram)

I assumed a 15X15 crossword and that 160 of the 225 squares had letters in them and all entries are real words.

I tried the approach of calculating the chance of at least one of each letter occurring over 160 squares. 1 -((1 - percentage of letter) ** 160).

I then took the product of these 26 values which came to 0.000300021186131477.

This seems far too low! Wht am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the letters are not independent. Also composers like "Cinephile" put together a number of problems indexed by letters of the alphabet (with no numbers in the grid, you have to fit the answers in as a jigsaw) - which would bias the answer somewhat in the world of real crosswords http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Galbraith_Graham

Answer (score 0):

For one, the model used may be wrong due to the many interdependencies in general (it is not just very unlikely, it is *impossible* that none of the letters occurs) and especially those inherent in a cross-word, but let's ignore this (as it is hard to account for it in any way that could be called right and we may assume the error is quite small). Also, crosswords are hand-crafted and may have other letter frequencies than plain English texts.

If all 26 letters had the same frequencies, you'd have $1-(\frac{25}{26})^{160}\approx 0.9981$ and this to the 26th power is $\approx 0.95\approx 1$. In other words: For a rough estmiate we may ignore the contribution of common letters, we have to concentrate on rare letters, which can spoil the high result.
Most letters have a [frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language) $>0.01$, but the rarest is **Z** with a frequency of $0.074\%=0.00074\approx 0.11$. Likewise, the next rarest letter **Q** contributes a factor $1-0.99905^{160}\approx0.14$, then **X** contributes $1-0.9985^{160}\approx 0.21$. Already the product of these numbers is merely $\approx0.003$. It is not surprising that the combined effort of the remaining (rare) letters can decrease this number by another factor of $0.1$ to the $0.0003$ you found.

Comment: Thanks for that. I realised that I was ignoring the many inter-dependencies and was worried that I had missed something obvious that was badly affecting my answer. This calculation resulted from discussion of pangrams on the fifteensquared website. Some setters sometimes try to "force" the pangram when they set the puzzle although they never indicate that this is the case. As the "chance" pangram is so rare it would appear futile to assume a pangram as a solving aid on the chance that the setter has engineered one.